# Erro ao tentar criar insert com python (TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str)

Tags: python, pandas

Estou tentando criar um arquivo de insert para o Sql com panda mas ao tentar este  código abaixo
ocorre o seguinte erro  TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str

```
  with open ("output.txt", "w"):
        for index, row in df.iterrows():
            print('INSERT INTO ' + TABLE_NAME + '(\'COD_TXT\' , \'DES_TXT\' ,\'DES_OBS_TXT\') VALUES (',
                  row['COD_TXT'],',\''+ row['DES_TXT'],',\''+row['DES_OBS_TXT']+'\');', file=open("output.txt", "a"))




TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um dos valores deve ser float em vez de string. É preciso usar a função str() para converter. Por exemplo:

```
str(row['COD_TXT'])
```